# Missing End Time - Google Calendar API call to insert event

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

Please help with why the code below returns an error stating the end date time is missing when trying to insert an event on behalf of another user in our domain (using the delegation)...

I can GET data from their calendars, just not POST the event.

I've tried it with and without the calendarId & resource in the request and with and without the timezones in the start/end objects. Everything else I've searched draws a blank.

```
function testRequest(){

  var service = getDWDS('Calendar: ', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar', 'user@example.com');

  var requestBody = 
    {
      calendarId: "user@example.com",
      resource: {
        start: {
          dateTime: '2022-12-09T09:00:00Z',
        },
        end: {
          dateTime: '2022-12-09T11:30:00Z',
        },

        summary: "Test Request",
        conferenceData: {
          createRequest: {
            requestId: 'random'
          }
        },
      }
    };
    requestBody.headers            = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + service.getAccessToken()};
    requestBody.contentType        = "application/json";
    requestBody.method             = "POST";
    requestBody.muteHttpExceptions = false;  

  var url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events?conferenceDataVersion=1&sendUpdates=none';

  Logger.log(requestBody)
  Logger.log(JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, requestBody)))

  return JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, requestBody));
}


const OAUTH2_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PRIVATE_KEY = "KEY GOES HERE"
const OAUTH2_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CLIENT_EMAIL = 'SERVICE ACCOUNT EMAIL HERE';

function getDWDS(serviceName, scope, email) {

  // Logger.log('starting getDomainWideDelegationService for email: ' + email);

  return OAuth2.createService(serviceName + email)
    // Set the endpoint URL.
    .setTokenUrl('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token')

    // Set the private key and issuer.
    .setPrivateKey(OAUTH2_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PRIVATE_KEY)
    .setIssuer(OAUTH2_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CLIENT_EMAIL)

    // Set the name of the user to impersonate. This will only work for
    // Google Apps for Work/EDU accounts whose admin has setup domain-wide
    // delegation:
    // https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#delegatingauthority
    .setSubject(email)

    // Set the property store where authorized tokens should be persisted.
    .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties())

    // Set the scope. This must match one of the scopes configured during the
    // setup of domain-wide delegation.
    .setScope(scope);

}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your script, I thought that the script for requesting Calendar API is required to be modified. And, in your script, 2 requests are done. So, how about the following modification?

In this modification, your `testRequest()` is modified.

#### Modified script:

```
function testRequest() {
  var service = getDWDS('Calendar: ', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar', 'user@example.com');
  var requestBody = {
    method: "POST",
    headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + service.getAccessToken() },
    contentType: "application/json",
    payload: JSON.stringify({
      start: { dateTime: '2022-12-09T09:00:00Z', },
      end: { dateTime: '2022-12-09T11:30:00Z', },
      summary: "Test Request",
      conferenceData: { createRequest: { requestId: 'random' } }
    }),
  };
  var url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events?conferenceDataVersion=1&sendUpdates=none';
  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, requestBody);
  return JSON.parse(res.getContentText());
}
```

#### Note:

- In this modification, it supposes that your access token of `service.getAccessToken()` is a valid access token for requesting the endtpoint of `'https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events`. Please be careful about this. When an error related to the authorization and the permission, please confirm your setting again.

#### References:

- [Events: insert](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/insert)
- [fetch(url, params)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params)

Comment: That's fantastic! Thank you!!

I'm guessing that this method can then be used in your batch scripting example on GitHub?

Comment: @JS Henney Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new question of `I'm guessing that this method can then be used in your batch scripting example on GitHub?`, I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understan your new question. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: I'm guessing this is your work...?

https://github.com/tanaikech/Managing-A-Lot-Of-Google-Calendar-Events-using-Batch-Requests-with-Google-Apps-Script

I can get this to run, but I need to be able to create the events as the users, so they control the Meet conferencing.

If not I will just create each event individually, rather than in a batch

Thanks again - your help is really appreciated

Comment: @JS Henney Thank you for replying. About `https://github.com/tanaikech/Managing-A-Lot-Of-Google-Calendar-Events-using-Batch-Requests-with-Google-Apps-Script`, this is my repository. So, I deeply apologize that my library was not useful for your situation. But, I cannot still understand your new question. But, I would like to support you. So, can you post it as a new question by including more information? By this, it will help users including me think of a solution. If you can cooperate to resolve your new question, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?